# Why does Borat call USA as US&A?

Tags: plot-explanation, borat-subsequent-moviefilm

In *Borat Subsequent Moviefilm (2020)*, why does Borat call USA as **US&A**? Is there any reason behind it?

Comment: It funny, yes..

Comment: from Borat wikipedia *broken English that appears poorly printed, indicating that there are "More movie discs available from US&A"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't see the movie yet, but it's full of intentional spelling/grammar errors:

- the title contains the 'duplicate word' Moviefilm
- the tag line 'Wear mask. Save live.' - even taking [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline) into account, that should be 'Save lives'.

'US&A' is probably just another intentional error. It even sort of reminds me that the word 'of' in 'United States of America' isn't included in the official abbreviation.

Comment: Also note the full titles of the two moviefilms: "Borat: Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan" and "Borat Subsequent Moviefilm: Delivery of Prodigious Bribe to American Regime for Make Benefit Once Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan".